# Font awesome in twig

Tags: symfony, templates, twig, font-awesome

I dont know why my icon doesn't appear in my page indeed i put the correct syntaxe. I put the link and icon.
Can you help me to resolve my issue?

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "C:\wamp64\www\crowdFunding\fontawesome-free-5.12.1-web\fontawesome-free-5.12.1-web\css\font–awesome.min.css" >

    <h1 class="far fa-eye">Comment ça marche ?</h1>
    <p><b> CrowdFunding Up permet de découvrir et donner vie à des projets originaux, créatifs, solidaires et innovants, à portée collective.</b></p>
    <p> Aussi appelé crowdFunding, le financement participatif est un mécanisme qui permet de récolter des fonds,
    généralement de petits montants, auprès d'un large public. 
    L'appel de fonds se fait à partir de la description d'un projet précis sur notre plateforme en ligne : CrowdFunding Up.</p>
    <h2> Vous pourrez : </h2>
    <ul>
        <li><i class="far fa-eye"></i> Lancer un projet </li>
        <li> Découvrir les projets de notre communauté</li>
        <li> Contribuer à un projet, de deux manières différentes
            <ol>En mettant des fonds pour le projet</ol>
            <ol>En donnant des idées d'améliorations</ol>
            <ol>En soutenant nos porteurs de projet</ol>
        </li>
        <li> Recevoir une contrepartie qui vous intéresse</li>
        <li> Discuter avec les membres de la communauté CrowdFunding Up</li>
    </ul>



{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Are you trying to access this from a server or from your local computer? If that is for a server, mind that you local C drive is hopefully not accessible to the world-wide-web

Comment: i tried both but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Finally i put this line of code `<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/ebc72dbf59.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>` in my html doc and it's working!! 
Thanks to all

Answer (score -1):

Extract the css/all.min.css and the entire webfonts directory out of the zip file to your DocumentRoot directory.

Your document root directory will like this:

```
- [css]
    |
    - all.min.css

- [webfonts]
    |
    - < about 15 font files >

- index.php
```

and include the css stylesheet in the head section of your html page:

```
<head>
  <link href="css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

Comment: In a more Symfony way of doing it, it would be better to install it via yarn and include it through webpack encore: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52316268/2123530