# Symfony 5 can't use Font Awesome icons

Tags: php, css, symfony, webpack, font-awesome

I am trying to import Font Awesome into my Symfony 5 with Webpack Encore project but I can't. I have read all the (most of them) [S.O questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51571170/how-to-add-fontawesome-5-to-symfony-4-using-webpack-encore), framework tutorials, etc. but none of the icons are being displayed.

### Steps I followed:

#### First attempt:

1. Compile assets and watch for changes with `yarn watch`
2. Install Font Awesome Free: `yarn add --dev @fortawesome/fontawesome-free`
3. Import CSS files into `app.css` file (`assets/css/app.css`):

```css
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/fontawesome.css';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/regular.css';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/solid.css';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/brands.css';
```

4. Add the icon to the TWIG template: `<i class="fas fa-star"></i>` ( I also tried to prepend the icon with `fa fa-star`, according to [Font Awesome documentation](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/referencing-icons/basic-use).

#### Second attempt:

1. Compile assets and watch for changes with `yarn watch`
2. Install Font Awesome Free: `yarn add --dev @fortawesome/fontawesome-free`
3. Import CSS / JS files into `app.js` file (`assets/js/app.js`):

```js
import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css';
import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all.js';
```

4. Import Solid Font Awesome icons into CSS file (`assets/css/app.css`) (and also in JS file):

```js
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/solid.css';
```

5. Add the icon to the TWIG template: `<i class="fas fa-star"></i>`

I also have tried using CSS  unicode:

```css
element {
    content: "\f005" 
}
```

None of them displays any icon, or any console error, warning, message, or anything, but I get an empty icon every time. Any clues?

Comment: add to css `font-family: FontAwesome;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first attempt is the right way, you just missed setting the `$fa-font-path` correctly.

```
$fa-font-path: '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands';
```

Comment: I have to use Sass instead of CSS only. it worked. Thank you.